# How to redirect to current location using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to redirect to current page using javascript from server side using this code ..

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", "<script>alert('Record saved with claim number " + lastid + ".');var currentPageUrl =document.location.toString().toLowerCase();window.location.assign('currentPageUrl')</script>", false);
```

But it does not work. How can I make it work?

Comment: @NK No its not a duplicate of that question because I was NOT looking for a way to RELOAD my page with javascript. I wanted to REDIRECT to the current URL using javascript. I made it clear in my comment on Ivan Doroshenko's answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: still, i wanted to redirect to current page. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just remove the quotes, because `currentPageUrl` is a JavaScript variable, but you pass it just as a string. change:

```
window.location.assign('currentPageUrl')
```

to

```
window.location.assign(currentPageUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Reload is not what was looking for.. the reason is that reload resubmit the form. So if I save some data on button click and then use reload then the button click even will get fired all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "success_msg_1", "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Record saved with claim number " + lastid + ".');location.replace('pageurl');</script>");
```